# A network-related or instance-specific error with C#

Tags: c#

I get an error like this:

> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: TCP Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server)

Here is my `apppsetting.json`:

```
  "DBInfo": 
  {
    "Name": "MySQLconnect",
    "ConnectionString": "server=localhost;user Id=root;password=root;database=cinemapanda4;"
  }
```

and here is my `StartUp.cs`:

```
public class Startup
{
   public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
   {
      Configuration = configuration;
   }
   public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

   // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
   public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
   {
      services.AddSession();
      services.AddDbContext<MyContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(Configuration["DBInfo:ConnectionString"]));
      services.AddControllersWithViews();
   }

   // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
   public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
   {
      app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
      app.UseStaticFiles();
      app.UseRouting();
      app.UseSession();
      app.UseAuthorization();
      app.UseEndpoints(endpoints => {
         endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
            name: "default",
            pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
      });
   }
}
```

I'm using MacBook and how can I fix this problem?

Comment: Your code says `UseSqlServer`, but then have `MySQLconnect` in the config file, are you using MySQL or Microsoft SQL Server?

Comment: Note that "SQL Server" is the name of a product, Microsoft SQL Server, it does not mean "A Server that supports SQL". So if you're trying to connect to MySQL, you can't use `UseSqlServer`, you will need to use something else.

Comment: Are you able to connect to that database with SSMS?

Comment: I'm using MySQL but when I change `options.UseSqlServer` to `options.MySql` and run command `dotnet ef database update -v` it cause me an error `Build failed. Use dotnet build to see the errors.`

Comment: It is not realistic to expect to connect to MySQL with SQL Server drivers.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're trying to use a MySQL database with EF Core, but connecting with SqlServer driver, which won't work. To connect to MySQL, you can use the [Pomelo Driver for EF Core](https://github.com/PomeloFoundation/Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql).

Configuration for which can be found here: https://github.com/PomeloFoundation/Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql#3-services-configuration